# How to match wildcard accept header when using @RequestMapping in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, http-headers

I have three resources:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "sample", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=text/html")
   public ResponseEntity<String> sampleResourceHtml()

   @RequestMapping(value = "sample", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml")
   public ResponseEntity<String> sampleResourceXml()

   @RequestMapping(value = "sample", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
   public ResponseEntity<String> sampleResourceJson()
```

When a HTTP client accesses the url with Accept=*/* the webapp returns a 404

In this case I want to invoke `sampleResourceHtml()`

Changing `"Accept=text/html"` to `"Accept=text/html, */*"` will make my webapp accept requests with Accept=*/* which is what I want, however it will also accept requests with Accept=foo/bar which is not what I want.

How do I modify my code to return a supported media type for requests containing wildcards without returning an unexpected media type for unsupported requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it easier to configure this in your context with the [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html), so that the *Accept* header is automatically handled and the conversion done by Spring and not programmatically.

For example, you could use the following configuration:

```
<bean id="xstreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller"/>
  <bean id="xmlMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
  <constructor-arg ref="xstreamMarshaller"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="messageConverters">
    <util:list>
      <ref bean="xmlMessageConverter"/>
      <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </util:list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And modify the controller to return the object which Spring will convert to the required type.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "sample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> sampleResource()
```

**Note:** You will need the relevant libraries on the classpath.

Comment: I assume I would have to add @RequestHeader("Accept") String accept as a method argument and parse the header myself. That's one of the things I was hoping to avoid by using the headers annotation.

Comment: Spring can return the representation of the object depending on the _Accept_ header on the request. Therefore if my request has `Accept="application/json"`, Spring will transform the object to JSON with just the simple `@RequestMapping` in the answer. If `Accept="text/xml"`, Spring would return the object as XML.